# Google tag script

Tags: magento-1.9, script

I try to add the google tag script in configuration > design > script but when I do this, the header of the front end show a white line.
This line isn't showed when there isn't the google script. It means that I added the script in the wrong section?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */var google_conversion_id =AAAAAAAAA;var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;var google_remarketing_only = true;/* ]]> */</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.AAAAAAA.com/AAAA/AAAAA.js"></script><noscript><div style="display:inline;"><img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"/></div></noscript>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code (no specific user/tracking id's) you're trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the

> Configuration->Design->Footer->Miscellaneous HTML

It should not be in the HTML head section. If you need to load it first, then you need to adjust template files far example at:

`app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/html/header.phtml.`

Comment: I also added the script to the footer > miscellaneous HTML, but the white line still exists.